# window.open Middle-Click in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

I need to use JavaScript to trigger a page to open in a new window when clicking the link. I've noticed that when you middle-click on the link in Firefox, you would open the current page in a new window instead of another page in a new window.

Note that I cannot do the following. This is because another application needs to read my code, and the link must be invoked via JavaScript.

```
<a href="http://www.google.ca" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4BuTg/

```
$('#link').click( function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.open( "http://www.google.ca", '_blank' );
});

<a href="" id="link" target="_blank">Middle Click This Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.click()`, I should have used `.bind()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can check the mouse down  event

http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

event.which also normalizes button presses (mousedown and mouseupevents), reporting 1 for left button, 2 for middle, and 3 for right. Use event.which instead of event.button.

Comment: event.which does not work in Firefox. I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to simply add the default behavior back to the link. Note that this code is untested, but I think it should fix the middle-button-problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').attr('href','http://www.google.com');
    $('#link').attr('target','_blank');
});
```

However, if this does not work, please explain further what you mean by the link has to be invoked by js.

Comment: Our website is also being read by an application. Our application, for whatever reason, does not open a new window when you do `<a href="url" target="_blank">link</a>`. Instead, I would have to do a JS call to `window.commonHelper.launchExternalBrowser(url);`.